# @media screen and (max-width: 1023px) not work on a 2K resolution screen

Tags: css, bulma

I'm tring to writing a navbar with bulma (a CSS library), and this is my code, which copies [bulma-templates](https://bulmatemplates.github.io/bulma-templates/templates/blog.html).

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="../">
                <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" alt="Logo">
            </a>
            <span class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="navbarMenu">
            </span>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</nav>
```

The CSS code of `.container` is:

```css
.navbar>.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .navbar>.container {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

I expect `.container` is a block at screen width ≤ 1023px, and should look like this.

[navbar when screen width = 1022px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivzqE.png)

but at screen width = 1023px, it looks like this

[navbar when screen width = 1023px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5fdy.png)

and the devtools show the width of navbar is 1023.2px, I guess this is what cause the problem.

[width of navbar when screen width = 1023px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVHMR.png)

I try different browser (Edge, Chrome, Firefox), the results are the same.

**I'm using a 2K screen**, so I try to set the resolution to 1080p, and the navbar works fine now.

[navbar when screen width = 1023px on 1080p resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spfb0.png)

Besides changing resolution, are there any other ways to fix it?

---

The Codepen Link of my code: https://codepen.io/ToddZZF/pen/mdQyLNG.

---

[This issue](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/3572) shows the same problem I have, and says change `max-width: 1023px` to `max-width: 1023.9px` can fix it.

Now I wonder where the extra 0.2px comes from?

Comment: Try to move default styles of `.container` to the beginning.

Comment: can you re-create a Codepen or any online example?

Comment: I change the default style to the beginning, and add the codepen link.

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width: 2048px)`?